# Does CSS3 offer a better way to have a two column website with header and footer, equal height columns and stretchy column widths?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I wrote a website a while ago that is a little messy in how it does things. I used this [CSS template](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/) and this [equal height columns trick](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight). I have not one but two container divs and I can't remember what they're doing. This seems unsatisfactory. So I'm thinking of restructuring the thing from scratch, and possibly making use of the more "semantic" html5 tags like `<nav>` and so on. I'm wondering if there are CSS3 type things I can do today that will improve the code.

The question is: is there a better way to achieve a site structure with these properties:

- 2 equal height columns: one navigational sidebar, one main content column (with widths as percentages of the available real estate, not explicitly stated)
- both a header and footer element that stretch the whole width of the total of the two main columns
- That allows the use of semantic html5 tags instead of several meaningless container divs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In css3 there are display properties that allow your divs to behave like html tables. I.E:

```
 #wrapper {
    display: table;
 }

 #wrapper div {
    display: table-cell;
 }
```

Even though at first sight it seems a regression to the old table days, in practice it's tremendously useful and the code ends very readable.

Here is a jsfiddle example with the kind of the kind of layout you're describing:
http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/SKxCH/

Comment: This is a neat solution [Here's a link I found useful on the topic](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/)

Comment: @Duopixel Is there a simple way to get a header cell to span both rows and fit above the nav and article cells?

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle with a working sample. There's no "colspan" in css3, so you have to take out the header and footer from the wrapper and then apply display: table to get the same behavior in these pieces.

Comment: @Duopixel Thanks! It seems that the `border-spacing` element can't take percentages as arguments. Is there a way to get "stretchy" border spacing?

Comment: You could fake it with an extra div between the nav and the article, ex: nav {width: 30%;} div {width:5%;} article{width:65%;}

Comment: @Duopixel Yeah I guess so, but if I want a header and footer as well I suddenly have a lot of messy extra `div`s which is what I was trying to avoid...

Answer (score 4):

In fact, CSS3 has a multi-column feature which allows you to divide an element into equal columns. Quirksmode.org has a good write up on it: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Give it a go; if you could get it working, I think it'd answer all your requirements. However, it doesn't work in IE, and even other browsers only implemented it recently. Judge for yourself, but my feeling is it might be a while yet before it has enough browser support to be worth using.

Comment: I'm not sure this does work for me anyway: I have two columns, one of which is a navigation column, the other is the body. So this kind of multi-column approach doesn't look like it will work...

Comment: @Seamus - ah right, I didn't get that from your question. Oh well, I hope the css-columns will come in handy for you one day.

Comment: yes, it's still a useful thing to know about. I'll edit the question to make clearer the issue I'm facing.