# Height dependent on screen size

Tags: css

I am using HTML5/CSS3 and what I am trying to do is create a page that scrolls if needed or is all on one section of the screen if there is less data.  At the moment I have not used a wrapper due to googling I was told that you could use body -> works fine.  As you see in my CSS I have set my `html,body` to `100%` and then on viewing the code it scrolls.

How could I make this screen size dependent?

```
html,body{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
    height:100%;
}
header{
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
header #logo{   
}
header nav{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
}
header nav ul li{
    float:right;
    height:40px;
    margin:0 0 0 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
header ul li a{
    color:#000;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content{
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    min-height:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#sidebar{
    float:right;
    width:250px;
    min-height:100%;
    border:1px solid green;
}

footer{
    clear: both;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}
```

Template Layout 2011
     
    
    
    </script>

```
    <div id="logo">
        <h1>Template Logo 2011</h1>
    </div><!--logo end -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Page One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page Four</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page Five</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="content">
        <h1>Content Introduction</h1>
        <p>Content</p>
    </section>
    <aside id="sidebar">
        <article id="box_one">
            <h2>Box One</h2>
            <p>Box Content</p>
        </article>

        <article id="box_two">
            <h2>Box Two</h2>
            <p>Box Content</p>
        </article>

        <article id="box_three">
            <h2>Box One</h2>
            <p>Box Content</p>
        </article>  
        </aside>
    <footer>
        <p>Footer content</p>
    </footer>
```

Comment: I'm not very clear on what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: usually html don't get styled and body tag don't get a height value.

Comment: Why have you set the height to 100%, exactly?

Comment: @Marlin,  What I am trying to do is have a site that sits with out a scroll content and the sidebar, footer sit nice,  but if a scroll is needed due to the amount of data it will expand

Comment: as i understand you want an sticky footer http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: @sandeep,  that appears to be part of it, but there is also a header defined here that will cause the scroll.  Jess.... if html, body, content and sidebar all have height set to 100% then anything outside of them, that isn't removed from the flow of the page, will cause this scroll issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for CSS3.  The main key is the display: table; display: table-cells;  used together gives you the matched height you are looking for without the divs or asides etc. being actual table cells.

```
            <!Doctype HTML>
            <html>
            <Head>
            <style type="text/css">
            html,body{
                margin:0 auto;
                width:960px;
            }
            header{
                width:100%;
                border-bottom:1px solid red;
            }
            header #logo{   
            }
            header nav{
                float:left;
                border:1px solid red;
                width:100%;
                margin:0 0 5px 0;
            }
            header nav ul li{
                float:right;
                height:40px;
                margin:0 0 0 15px;
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            header ul li a{
                color:#000;
                font-size:14px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            #wrapper{
                display: table;
                width: 960px;
                border: 1px solid blue;
            }

            #content{
                display: table-cell;
                width:700px;
                border:1px solid red;
                min-height: 250px;
            }

            #sidebar{
                display: table-cell;
                width:250px;
                border:1px solid green;
            }

            footer{
                clear: both;
                width:100%;
                height:40px;
            }

            </style>
            </head>
            <body>

                <div id="logo">
                    <h1>Template Logo 2011</h1>
                </div><!--logo end -->
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Page One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page Three</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page Four</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page Five</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                <div id="wrapper">    
                <div id="content">
                    <h1>Content Introduction</h1>
                    <p>Content</p>
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <article id="box_one">
                        <h2>Box One</h2>
                        <p>Box Content</p>
                    </article>

                    <article id="box_two">
                        <h2>Box Two</h2>
                        <p>Box Content</p>
                    </article>

                    <article id="box_three">
                        <h2>Box One</h2>
                        <p>Box Content</p>
                    </article>  
                 </div>
                </div>
                <footer>
                    <p>Footer content</p>
                </footer>    

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Thats the thing tho there is not enough content for it to warrant the scroll and 100% height -> http://cl.ly/3L3X431v3S1f2e2L0624 it should stop when required to let the footer take over

Comment: The Key is he wrapper display: table; and then setting your table-cells;  This is as of CSS3 not sure about backwards compatibility with this. here's a link to a reference [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874847/does-css3-offer-a-better-way-to-have-a-two-column-website-with-header-and-footer)